# Heuristic for Maximum Coverage variant

Tags: algorithm, set, heuristics

I have the following problem:
There are N groups. Each group is a collection of sets. 
The goal is to choose exactly one set from each of the N groups such that the size of the set that is the union of all of your choices is maximized.
The number of sets in each group is not necessarily the same, but is bounded is bounded by some number, M.

For example,

```
1. {6, 7, 8}, {10} 
2. {6,7}, {8,9} 
3. {10}, {1,2}, {99}
```

Has an actual answer of `6` because you can choose `{6,7,8}` from 1, `{8,9}` from 2, and `{1,2}` from 3, making the union `{1,2,6,7,8,9}` which has a size of `6`.

In my particular domain, the problem structure always obeys the following rules:
N varies from 1 to 2000. The numbers in the sets are from 1 to 50. The maximum size of an individual set is 5 and the absolute difference between any two numbers in a given set cannot exceed 2 (a set can contain `j`, `j+1`, `j-1`, `j+2`, or `j-2`).

I don't think that I can solve these problems perfectly fast enough. So I have come up with the following heuristics:

1. The size is upper bounded by the size of the union of every set in every group (would give 8 for the above example)
2. The size is upper bounded by the sum of the size of the largest set in every group. (would give 7 for the above example)
3. The size is upper bounded by min(heuristic1, heuristic2)

I don't think there is an efficient algorithm for computing the size exactly (although I'd love to be proven wrong). But if anyone can see a heuristic that could give an even tighter bound (and is efficient to compute), that would be awesome.

EDIT: For my particular use case, I'm only interested in upper bounds. I need to be able to say with certainty the size is no more than a specific number, otherwise the heuristic is useless to me.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any relationship between the groups and sets that can be exploited?

If not, how about a simple greedy algorithm where you start with the empty set then for each group you add the set that has the most elements not in the current solution:

1. Let *T* = {∅}, N = 1
2. Select set *S*<sub>k</sub> ∈ {*S*<sub>1</sub>, ..., *S*<sub>M</sub>} in group *N* such that *S*<sub>k</sub> = **max**<sub>i</sub>(|*S*<sub>i</sub> \ *T*|)
3. Let *T* = *T* ∪ *S*<sub>k</sub>
4. If last group exit else N = N + 1 and go to Step 2.

The answer will clearly be dependent on a few issues:

- The initial group
- The order the groups are processed
- Selecting *S*<sub>k</sub> when **max** is not unique

To mitigate against these issues you can track more than one solution *T*. For example, at every step keep the top 2 or 3 solutions. And then upon exit keep the largest solution.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's a good idea. But (and I'm sorry, but I completely forgot to mention this in the initial question posting) I'm actually only looking for upper bounds, and this seems like a lower bound.